# android Login and Registration error, connection is not incurring between localhost and emulator

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am struggling with this problem. I have tried to to create a login & Registration page using volley library, php and mysql. The code works fine , there is no error. but as soon as i click on register button the data is not inserting into DB. I have tried changing the Appconfig config file with localhost to 10.0.2.2 then i also added Appcontroller to the application, still the connection is not creating and data is not inserting into DB. My firewall is also disabled. What do i do? I am really stuck.

Here is my code:

```
Register.java
package com.example.mi.mikpitool;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.example.mi.mikpitool.R;

import com.example.mi.mikpitool.AppConfig;
import com.example.mi.mikpitool.AppController;
import com.example.mi.mikpitool.SQLiteHandler;
import com.example.mi.mikpitool.SessionManager;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
     Button btnRegister;
     Button btnLinkToLogin;
    private EditText inputFullName;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    registerUser(name, email, password);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
     * email, password) to register url
     * */
    private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                              final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                        // Now store the user in sqlite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                RegisterActivity.this,
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}






Appconfig.java
package com.example.mi.mikpitool;
 public class AppConfig {
    // Server user login url
     public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/AndroidLoginAndRegistration-v2/android_login_api/login.php";

    // Server user register url
    public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/AndroidLoginAndRegistration-v2/android_login_api/register.php";
}





 SqliteHandler.java
        package com.example.mi.mikpitool;
        import android.content.ContentValues;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
        import android.util.Log;
        import java.util.HashMap;

        public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

            // All Static variables
            // Database Version
            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

            // Database Name
            private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mikpi";

            // Login table name
            private static final String TABLE_USER = "users";

            // Login Table Columns name
            private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
            private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
            private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
            private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
            private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

            public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            // Creating Tables
            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                        + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                        + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
                db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

                Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
            }

            // Upgrading database
            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                // Drop older table if existed
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

                // Create tables again
                onCreate(db);
            }

            /**
             * Storing user details in database
             * */
            public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
                values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
                values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
                values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

                // Inserting Row
                long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
                db.close(); // Closing database connection

                Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
            }

            /**
             * Getting user data from database
             * */
            public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
                HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
                    user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
                    user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
                    user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                // return user
                Log.d(TAG, "Fetching users from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

                return user;
            }

            /**
             * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
             * */
            public void deleteUsers() {
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                // Delete All Rows
                db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
                db.close();

                Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all users info from sqlite");
            }

        }
```

I am struggling with it from last 2 days. Please tell me what is missing or why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of localhost, use your systems IP address.

e.g. If your URL is

```
http://localhost/some_file.php
```

Then the URL to be used in your app should be

```
http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx/some_file.php.
```

Comment: tried that as well. didn't work. It was not working with loalhost/ 127.0.0.1, thats why i used 10.0.2.2

Comment: Have you tested this url http://10.0.2.2:8080/AndroidLoginAndRegistration-v2/android_login_api/register.php in rest client? Is this works on your rest client?

Comment: Try using your systems ip address.

Comment: What are you getting in response?

Comment: using http://10.0.2.2:8080/AndroidLoginAndRegistration-v2/android_login_api/register.php  gives me site can't be reached